# If you cut a part in two (parts vs. pieces)

Tags: meaning

If you cut something in half, do you get two *parts* or two *pieces*? Do they convey different meanings? This is in the context of a mechanical part physically cut in two.

Comment: Is this a question about English or a question about mechanical engineering? If the former, it is general reference. If the latter, it is too narrowly circumscribed to be of general interest to ELU readers. Either way, I am voting to close.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the context of a mechanical assembly, I would understand 'part' to refer to a component or subassembly which might have been dismounted from the whole, while 'piece' would be an arbitrary fragment, e.g. that resulting from a straight cut or break.